# How to debug invalid encoding even in substring

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

The behaviour of how string validation is calculated is baffling me e.g.

I have a data loaded from file, and for that ruby says it has invalid encoding

```
irb(main):160:0> data = File.open("data.txt").read
irb(main):171:0> data.valid_encoding?
=> false
```

If I take substring out of that data it still shows up as invalid, though codepoints or bytes doesn't show any invalid chars

```
irb(main):172:0> s=data[11933300..11933318]
=> "******************\n"
irb(main):174:0> s.valid_encoding?
=> false
irb(main):175:0> s.codepoints.to_a
=> [42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 10]
irb(main):176:0> s=data[11933302..11933318]
=> "****************\n"
irb(main):177:0> s.valid_encoding?
=> false
irb(main):178:0> s.codepoints.to_a
=> [42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 10]
```

but a smaller substr comes up as correct encoding?

```
irb(main):179:0> s=data[11933308..11933318]
=> "**********\n"
irb(main):180:0> s.valid_encoding?
=> true
irb(main):181:0> s.codepoints.to_a
=> [42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 10]
```

This looks like a bug where original data may have invalid chars but how come a substr without any invalid chars is still coming up as invalid encoding, and actions like `s.split("\n")` throw errors e.g.

```
irb(main):155:0> s.split(".")
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    from (irb):155:in `split'
    from (irb):155
```

I am using ruby 1.9.1 on linux, and locale is set to UTF-8

Comment: Do know what is the supposed encoding for your file?

Comment: It is UTF-8, my concern here is not actually to find the char, but to see why a substring still have a invalid encoding, but none of its bytes are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, `String#force_encoding("utf-8")` is perhaps what you want?  Apply it to your string object.

Phylosophically speaking, I think it is fair when the character code of the original string is invalid, that of any of its substring will be also invalid, because the *slice* you make may not make sense in terms of the character encoding.  For example, when each character of the original string is supposed to have 3 bytes and if you slice the string from the 2nd character of the original string, then the resultant substring should not have a valid encoding, but instead it should be regarded as a pure byte array.  So, when Ruby regards the character code of the original string as invalid, then Ruby by definition would not know if any of its substring has a valid character-code, except for the empty string.

What is most buffling to me in this case is your third example, which gives `s.valid_encoding? == true`, whereas the others don't.

In the most recent Ruby-2.1.4, it seems to me that a substring created by `String#[]` basically inherits the encoding and related characteristics from its original string, and then the encoding may be redefined, depending on the condition.

The corresponding functions are,
`rb_str_aref()` →
`rb_str_substr()` →
`rb_enc_cr_str_copy_for_substr()` →
`str_enc_copy()` in `string.c` in the source code.  Also,
`ENCODING_GET()` defined in `include/ruby/encoding.h`
and `rb_enc_get_index()` in `encoding.c` are called/used.

However, I haven't found any indication different substrings may end up having a different status of `String#valid_encoding?`

The thing is, Ruby 1.9.1 you are using is a pretty old development track, which is fairly buggy in my vague memory, even though the specifications of Ruby 1.9 and 2.0 are not much different.  That might explain?